# Add a year to a range of values - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to add a year to any value that its added to a column. I dont want to paste to a new column but rather replace values on the same column.

The code ive written so far is:

```
Private Sub Update_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim path As String, fileName As String
    Dim lastRowInput As Long, lastRowOutput As Long, rowCntr As Long, lastColumn As Long
    Dim inputWS1 As Worksheet, outputWS As Worksheet

    Set inputWS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Universal")
    Set outputWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Carriers")


    rowCntr = 1

    lastRowInput = inputWS1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowOutput = outputWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastColumn = inputWS1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    inputWS1.Range("A4:A" & lastRowInput).Copy outputWS.Range("B2")
    inputWS1.Range("B4:B" & lastRowInput).Copy outputWS.Range("C2")
    outputWS.Range("E2:E" & (lastRowInput - 2)).Value = inputWS1.Name
    inputWS1.Range("J4:J" & lastRowInput).Copy outputWS.Range("G2")
    inputWS1.Range("G2:G" & lastRowInput).Value = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, CDate(inputWS1.Range("G2:G" & lastRowInput)))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 

End Sub
```

The line i need you guys to help me is :

> DateAdd("yyyy", -1, CDate(inputWS1.Range("G2:G" & lastRowInput)))

where inputWS1 is the name of my sheet and lastrowinput is my variable to find the last row on the column. at the time i place this code there is already values on G2 and i just want to transform them into last years date on the same column they are.

Please help

Comment: you want to add a year to a column of cells when you click a button.  ... how many times are you planning on clicking the button?

Comment: Actually once a month, because the button will import new data in cells. However it just overwrites the old data with the data from the previous cell. So basically everytime I click the button it clears everything on New sheet and copies it from old sheet.

Comment: you should have mentioned that you are deleting the worksheet content. i was trying to figure out a mechanism for updating a year only once across multiple macro runs

Comment: Apologies.  this is a document that monthly takes info from several sheets. The info on these sheets is not deleted so the document running the macro retakes all the info every month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also use Evaluate Function to perform the calculation at once like below...

```
inputWS1.Range("G2:G" & lastRowInput).Value = Evaluate("=IF(ISNUMBER(G2:G" & lastRowInput & "),DATE(YEAR(G2:G" & lastRowInput & ")-1,MONTH(G2:G" & lastRowInput & "),DAY(G2:G" & lastRowInput & ")),G2:G" & lastRowInput & ")")
```

Incorporate the above line in your code where you want to subtract the year by one in column G.

Comment: I tested this code with some dummy data and it worked without an issue. e.g. if date in G2 in InputWS1 is 09/01/2017, it gets changed to 09/01/2016. Isn't that what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert  specific value  of cell with dateadd function.

```
Private Sub Update_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim path As String, fileName As String
Dim lastRowInput As Long, lastRowOutput As Long, rowCntr As Long, lastColumn As Long
Dim inputWS1 As Worksheet, outputWS As Worksheet

Set inputWS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Universal")
Set outputWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Carriers")


rowCntr = 1

lastRowInput = inputWS1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowOutput = outputWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = inputWS1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

inputWS1.Range("A4:A" & lastRowInput).Copy outputWS.Range("B2")
inputWS1.Range("B4:B" & lastRowInput).Copy outputWS.Range("C2")
outputWS.Range("E2:E" & (lastRowInput - 2)).Value = inputWS1.Name
inputWS1.Range("J4:J" & lastRowInput).Copy outputWS.Range("G2")
'inputWS1.Range("G2:G" & lastRowInput).Value = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, CDate(inputWS1.Range("G2:G" & lastRowInput)))
Dim vDB As Variant, i As Long
vDB = inputWS1.Range("G2:G" & lastRowInput) '<~~ get data to variant array vDB
For i = 1 To UBound(vDB,1)
    vDB(i, 1) = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, CDate(vDB(i, 1)))
Next i
inputWS1.Range("G2:G" & lastRowInput) = vDB


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: i get an error at line "    vDB(i, 1) = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, CDate(vDB(i, 1))) " .